# Golang and Visual Studio Code Intellisense Auto Suggest Custom Package Type

Tags: go, package, go-modules, goland

I'm working to accomplish something similar to GoLand IDE, but with Visual Studio Code, where typing "SomeType" would auto-suggest via a popup to choose the custom package to choose "SomeType" from. [image]

In GoLand, the following setting has to be enabled to accomplish the above.

Preferences > Enable module integration

My directory structure:

```
016-Packages
 |
 +-- helpers
 |     |
 |     +-- helpers.go
 +-- go.mod
 +-- main.go
```

helpers.go file:

```
package helpers

type SomeType struct {
    TypeName   string
    TypeNumber int
}
```

go.mod file:

```
module 016-packages

go 1.19
```

main.go file:

```
package main

func main() {

    var myVar SomeType
}
```

When I mouse hover over "SomeType", the auto suggestion shows "undeclared name" instead of "helpers.SomeType". [image]

If I type "helpers.SomeType" and press Ctrl-s in Visual Studio Code, it'll add the:

```
import "016-packages/helpers"
```

automatically above and then show the suggestion as in the following picture:

[image]

In summary, I would like to only type "SomeType" and have the auto-suggestion popup with the "helpers.SomeType" be a choice as with GoLand.

Thank you for any suggestions.